# How to specify foreign key in association query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

How can I specify a **foreign key**, when i make a query that include another model, because i have many foreign keys for that model.

```
DBTweet.findAll({ where: { userID: followingUserID }, include: [
            { model: DBUser, 
        include: [
                { model: DBFollower // Here i want to specify the foreign key },
        ] },
]})
```

UPDATE:

When i have two associations  with as

> users is associated to followers multiple times. To identify the correct association, you must use the 'as' keyword to specify the alias of the association you want to include

```
DBFollower.findAll({ where: { followerUserID: req.params.userID }, include: [ 
    { model: DBUser, attributes: { exclude: ['email', 'password', 'loginType', 'telephoneNumber'] }}
]})
```

Those are my associations :

```
DBUser.hasMany(DBTweet, { foreignKey: 'userID' }, { onDelete: 'cascade' })
DBTweet.belongsTo(DBUser, {foreignKey: 'userID'}, { onDelete: 'cascade' })

DBUser.hasMany(DBFollower, { as: 'followingUserIDAlias', foreignKey: 'followingUserID' }, { onDelete: 'cascade' })
DBFollower.belongsTo(DBUser, { as: 'followingUserIDAlias', foreignKey: 'followingUserID' }, { onDelete: 'cascade' })

DBUser.hasMany(DBFollower, { as: 'followerUserIDAlias', foreignKey: 'followerUserID' }, { onDelete: 'cascade' })
DBFollower.belongsTo(DBUser, { as: 'followerUserIDAlias', foreignKey: 'followerUserID' }, { onDelete: 'cascade' })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DBTweet.findAll({ 
  where: { userID: followingUserID }, 
  include: [{ 
    model: DBUser,
    as: 'Users', //here goes the alias as well
    include: [{ 
      model: DBFollower, 
      as: 'Followers' //here is goes the alias of the association
    }],
  }]
});


module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const DBUser = sequelize.define('DBUser', {
    // your attributes
  });

  DBUser.associate = (models) => {
    DBUser.hasMany(models.DBFollower,  {  as: 'Followers',  foreignKey: 'your_key' });
    // DBUser.belongsTo(models.DBFollower,  {  as: 'Followers',  foreignKey: 'branch_id' });
  };

  return DBUser;
};
```

UPDATE:

Now with your associations:

```
DBUser.hasMany(DBTweet, { as: 'Users', foreignKey: 'userID', onDelete: 'cascade' })
DBTweet.belongsTo(DBUser, { as: 'Users', foreignKey: 'userID', onDelete: 'cascade' })

DBUser.hasMany(DBFollower, { as: 'followingUserIDAlias', foreignKey: 'followingUserID', onDelete: 'cascade' })
DBFollower.belongsTo(DBUser, { as: 'followingUserIDAlias', foreignKey: 'followingUserID', onDelete: 'cascade' })

DBUser.hasMany(DBFollower, { as: 'followerUserIDAlias', foreignKey: 'followerUserID', onDelete: 'cascade' })
DBFollower.belongsTo(DBUser, { as: 'followerUserIDAlias', foreignKey: 'followerUserID', onDelete: 'cascade' })
```

Comment: i have two hasMany associations from DBUser to DBFollower with as: i get this error: users is associated to followers multiple times. To identify the correct association, you must use the 'as' keyword to specify the alias of the association you want to include

Comment: As the error says, you need to put an alias on each association. To avoid this, always use an alias.

Comment: If i do as: in DBFollower findAll query i get the same error. See question  again

Comment: Can you please update with the associations of `DBTweet`, `DBUser` and `DBFollower`

Comment: See question again

Comment: Add and alias also on the relation between `DBUser` and `DBTweet`. Also you are forgetting to add `as` on your second query. See my example

Comment: Could you make me an example. I don't know what to do